# How to rewrite only category and heading of the page in URL web config

Tags: web-config

I was trying to change the URL by using this rule:

```
<rule name="Rewrite to news page">
    <match url="^news/([_0-9a-z-]+)/([\s\S]+)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="page.php?id={R:1}&amp;title={R:2}" />
</rule>
```

but I don't want to use an id in the URL.

Comment: It does not look like `.htaccess` rewrite rule. PHP does not have that thing. What framework are you using?

Comment: it's web config rule .

Comment: Please tag your question properly. If it's `.net` question or not.

Comment: If your script currently relies on the ID to fetch the correct content from the database, then of course you will have to modify that part as well ...

Comment: Not related to PHP in any way. Please use the correct tags if you want to get an answer.

Comment: It's a web config rule to change the URL link